# Site MVC C# apresenta a mensagem "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials." após login em acesso externo

Tags: c#, mvc, servidor, iis

Criei o site MVC C# normal sem nenhuma peculiaridade.
No Controller Default o index ficou dessa forma.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginUsuarioVM model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var usuarioVM = Mapper.Map<Usuario, UsuarioVM>(UsuarioApplication.BuscarPorLoginSenha(model.Login, model.Senha));

            if (usuarioVM != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie($"{usuarioVM.Nome};{usuarioVM.IdUsuario}", model.Remember);

                return RedirectToAction("Home");
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["UsuarioInvalido"] = "Usuário ou Senha Inválido !";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Default");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["UsuarioInvalido"] = "Usuário ou Senha Inválido !";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Default");
        }
    }
```

Se o login estiver OK direciona para a Home.

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home";
        return View();
    }
```

No `Web.config` defini a system.web desta forma

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXFORMSDEMO" loginUrl="~/Default/Index" timeout="1440" protection="All" path="/" />
</authentication>
    <authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AuthRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AuthRoleProvider" type="MVC.AuthRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Foi publicado no servidor IIS 8.5. Por questões internas não está dentro do `Defaul Web Sites`.
O pool está como `.NET v4.5 Classic`, `Pipeline Classic` e `Porta 1435`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A Authentication no IIS está da seguinte forma:

[image: Aba Authentication]

Com Usuário especificado IUSR.
[image: Usuário adicionado]

A questão é:

Acessando o site em localhost ou acessando pelo "nome do servidor/Site" dentro da rede a aplicação abre e loga normalmente. Acessando ela pela url externa depois do login apresenta a mensagem de erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já foi dada a permissão na pasta para o IUSR.
[image: Permissão de pasta]

Não consigo encontrar onde está o problema se na aplicação ou na configuração do servidor.

Espero ter sido claro na explicação e obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se as credenciais para usuários anônimos estão direcionadas corretamente em **Authentication**:

- Clique em **Anonymous Authentication**;
- Clique em **Edit**, na extrema direita superior;
- Veja se o usuário selecionado é o correto ou se você quer utilizar o **App Pool Identity**.

Se não for o caso, tente habilitar as páginas de erro detalhadas:

- Clique em **Error Pages**;
- Clique **Edit feature settings**;
- Selecione **Ativar** e dê OK.

Comment: O usuário selecionado na aba Anonymous é o IUSR. Também fiz o teste com selecionando o App Pool Identity e continua com o mesmo erro (esse site tá zicado).